# RPi3 and larger touch screen monitors

Tags: touchscreen

I want to use a [Hanns-G HT225HPB 21.5"](http://www.hannspree.eu/en/monitors/ht-series/HT225HPB) touch screen monitor with my Pi3B. This has a HDMI interface and a USB connection but says it is for 'Windows10'. The monitor works great but I can't get the touch to work at all. I have tried the USB connection to the Pi to no avail. Seems the HP L2105tm works OK but mine doesn't. At £180 it was a good buy and we want to use these for 'control panels' for a club model railway. It will use JAVA and JMRI. This works well on a Pi3 but only with a real mouse.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could specify the model number in the question (not in the comments). An unproductive 10 minutes in Google has failed to turn up any Hanns-G 22" touchscreen models. They do, however, seem to have a 23" model.

Comment: Maybe you didn't search on the right subject? The model is a HT225HPB.

Comment: That'd be the 21.5" model, but who's counting?

Comment: Does the touchscreen work with regular PC computers? For all we know, your device might just be faulty.

Answer (score 2):

I can now answer my own question. The HANNS-G HT225HPB monitor works with my Pi3 (Jessie) without any extra drivers. It is a plug-and-play. However, I did need to install the xinput-calibrator.

sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator

This now appears as an option in the preferences list and is a single point on the screen. Easy to use. The touch is now in the right place.

This is a really good monitor, at £180, and a good option if you want a large screen touch display instead of the 'official' but too small ones.

Mike B

Comment: Can you comment on whether multitouch is available, and which OS version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably out of luck as when a touch screen is listed as incompatible with the os you are using it is unlikely that you will find drivers for it

Comment: However, the same monitor USB connects to a Win 7 machine as a HID device and works. Why not on the Pi? how can I find what USB drivers are included in the latest Jessie? I have found a Ubuntu Linux driver for this monitor. Would that work and how do I install it?

Comment: @Mike_B you can run ubuntu on the Pi and windows 7 will automatically download drivers when a touch screen is plugged in

Comment: @MohammadAli I'm struggling with that comment. Why would Windows 7 download a driver when you've got a touchscreen connected to a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu?

Comment: @Mike_B The important bit about Linux drivers for the Pi is that they have to be compiled to work specifically with the ARM chip the Pi uses as its CPU. More often than not Linux drivers are compiled for x86 chips. You may be lucky however - you need to check the manufacturer's webpage to find out which versions are available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Jessie & a Pi3. 
A firmware update of the monitor solved my problem.
For the update you need a windows pc.
After the update the touch (single click) works fine.

At the support website of Hannspree you can download the firmware:
http://www.hannspree.eu/en/faq-touch-monitor#faqa3-2

I also used xinput-calibrator afterwards to fine tune the touch target detection.

Comment: link is dead, but the firmware updater can still be downloaded. Google for TC_PTool_2008. Currently it is downloadable here: https://www.hannspree.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/WIN8.rar